# I'm trying to run a java file that reads in a text file in the same directory but it says the file isn't found

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm trying to run a java class that reads in a txt file and even though the text file is in the exact same folder as the class, it says it can't find it. the exact error is

"Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: Employees.txt (No such file or directory)"

Comment: SUGGESTION: Add `System.out.println("Current directory: " + System.getProperty("user.dir"));` to your class and run it.  Make sure your "Employees.txt" is in that directory.

Comment: If you just specify the file name then the system looks in the "current working directory" for the file - this is probably **not** the directory containing the class.